# How do you make multiple listeners for one button in GUI?

Tags: java

How do you make multiple action listeners for one button? For example I have a button named "Start" and the 1st time I click the button it prints out in GUI "Starting up", and the name of the button should change to "Stop". When the "Stop" button is pressed again the text field should say"Cant stop now!!", and the name of the button should change back to "Start". Here is my code so far. Eclipse keeps coming up with errors so I cant add another listener after the Start Button is clicked the second time.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Driver {

    private static JTextField textfield;

    public static void main( String[]args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        final JButton Start = new JButton( "Start");
//      JButton Stop = new JButton( "Stop");


        final int FIELD_WIDTH = 20;
        textfield = new JTextField( FIELD_WIDTH);

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        textfield.setText("My cool program");

            Start.addActionListener(new
            ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    Start.setText("Stop");
                    textfield.setText("Starting up....");
                }

            }); 


        frame.add(Start);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(textfield);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }

    private static ActionListener createGreetingButtonListener(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Start by reading the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

One listener is enough. you should just define somekind of a counter or boolean inside of a listener, and than check which turn is it.

This is psevdo code:

```
click(){
  if(bool == true){
     set start
     bool = false
  }
  else if(bool == false){
     set stop
     bool = true
  }
}
```